# An error produced when using the caption package

Tags: errors, captions

My .tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,portrait,12pt,openright,final,pdflatex]{report}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=8mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex,linktocpage=true,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black,pdfauthor={Ayman Elmasry},pdftitle={Algorithmic Form Generation: A Thermal Building
Envelope Design Approach}}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

I compile with pdflatex, and I get this error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
Runaway argument?
{\caption@CheckCommand \@makecaption {\long \def \@makecaption ##1##2\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.901         \unskip\kern-2\captionindent\par
```

When I comment out:

```
%\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
```

... I get an output PDF file with no problems.

Comment: Please post a full minimal example: the snippet you give is not enough to work from.

Comment: @JosephWright: as in the full preamble an the whole log?

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @JosephWright: OK, this my first 'minimal example', I hope it's right that way.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is a bug in `arabtex` which redefines `\@gobble` to be non-long.

```
\documentclass{article}
{\makeatletter\typeout{\meaning\@gobble}}
\usepackage{arabtex}
{\makeatletter\typeout{\meaning\@gobble}}
\stop
```

One first gets `\long macro:#1->`, then `macro:#1->`.  Macros must be `\long` to allow `\par` in their argument, hence the problem.  One solution is to add `{\makeatletter\long\gdef\@gobble#1{}}` just after loading `arabtex`.

```
\usepackage{arabtex}
{\makeatletter\long\gdef\@gobble#1{}}
```

This restores the original definition of the LaTeX kernel function `\@gobble`.

Comment: Indeed that's the problem in my case! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The error is not because of the caption package as the following MWE demonstrates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\begin{document}
\captionof{figure}{Just a test.}
\end{document}
```

It is always best to provide a minimal working example. I suggest you start removing lines from your code, or inserting `\end{document}` progressively until you identify the source of the error (possibly an unprotected command in caption text).

**Edit**

The arabtex package and utf8 both clash with the caption package. The arabtex package redefines quite a few items for R-L writing. Suggest removing them.

Comment: I've added an MWE in my question above. I hope it's correct that way.

Comment: @AymanElmasry Your example is fine now, it demonstrates the error. Once you have a MWE is easy for you to trace the source. You can comment package by package out until you find the clash. The `arabtex` package gave me problems in the past with footnotes and I couldn't fix them.