# Error while including subcaption package

Tags: subcaption

I am new user to latex and trying to write my thesis in latex. I have received a template in latex that uses following packages. When I try to include `\usepackage{subcaption}` to include subfigures in my thesis, file does not compile and error appears. I dont know which of the following packages is conflicting with subcaption package
Best Regards

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{utf8}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\geometry{  b5paper,
            total={185mm,255mm},
            left=25mm,
            right=25mm,
            top=25mm,
            bottom=25mm,
            }
\doublespacing
\hypersetup{urlcolor=black, colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue}
\title{\ttitle}
```

Comment: A more comprehensive MWE is `\documentclass{report}\usepackage{arabtex}\usepackage{caption}\begin{document}A\end{document}` and the error message is `Runaway argument? {\caption@CheckCommand \@makecaption {\long \def \@makecaption ##1##2\ETC. ! Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete.` so it seems it's an incompatibility between `arabtex` and `caption`. I'll take a closer look at it on Saturday. Until then, try loading `arabtex` as last package in order.

Comment: From the `arabtex` documentation: "ArabTEX tries to diagnose the presence of some other packages with which it could run into conflicts, and sometimes locally modifies itself accordingly. For this to be possible, in case of doubt the ArabTEX package should be loaded last."

Comment: Update: Loading `arabtex` as last package does not help here since the `caption` package bundle relies on a proper definition of `\@gobble`. Maybe it won't throw errors anymore but the outcome could be typeset wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A more comprehensive MWE is

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
  A
\end{document}
```

and the error message is

```
Runaway argument?
{\caption@CheckCommand \@makecaption {\long \def \@makecaption ##1##2\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par
```

Why is `\@gobble` disturbed by a `\par`? This one will show the main problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter\show\@gobble\makeatother
\usepackage{arabtex}
\makeatletter\show\@gobble\makeatother
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

When running this document it comes clear that `arabtex` is redefining the internal LaTeX macro `\@gobble` from `\long\def\@gobble#1{}` to `\def\@gobble#1{}` which IMHO is clearly a fatal bug.

This makes the whole `caption` package bundle doomed to fail since (like many other packages) it relies of the proper definition of some internal LaTeX commands like `\@ifundefined`, `\@gobble`, `\@firstofone`, `\@firstoftwo` and so on.

As a workaround one can restore the definition of `\@gobble` after loading `arabtex`:

```
\documentclass{report}
%
\usepackage{arabtex}
% arabtex cripples \@gobble, so we need to restore it
\makeatletter
\long\def\@gobble#1{}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{caption}
%
\begin{document}
  A
\end{document}
```

However, this bug should be reported to the maintainer of `arabtex`. This definitely needs to be fixed and I strongly doubt that the `caption` package is the only one which struggles with this.

Update: A quick internet search shows that this is a duplicate question of [An error produced when using the caption package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42231/an-error-produced-when-using-the-caption-package) , and furthermore that this bug hasn't been fixed for years.

Update #2: Since there is no sign that this bug will be fixed in `arabtex` I added a workaround to the `caption` package. So if you run into this problem, just update your TeX distribution and the problem should get away. See also: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/33/

Comment: I found that \usepackage{arabtex} was creating problem. This problem is solved by including \usepackage{caption} and \usepackage{subcaption} before including the \usepackage{arabtex}

Comment: @shahid No, changing the load order won't solve all problems. I can create you a ton of example documents which would show strange behavior anyway. The only real solution is restoring the definition of `\@gobble` after loading `arabtex`.