# Problem with figure and table caption

Tags: captions

I'm writing a thesis using latex. I had the following  a error when I add the figure caption:

```
l. 91 \caption{Chevauchement et ligature}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text.
```

when I write the same code in a new file it's work, but not in my thesis. Any help please?

[thesis files in the link](http://www.filedropper.com/rapportthse)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question is unclear; can you show the code that causes the failure?

Comment: Try isolating the problem by removing parts of the document until you get no error and then narrowing the part the error may be caused by as mich as you can. And check your braces: the error suggests you mau be missing one.

Comment: I tried to add code to explain more the problem thanks!!

Comment: Your MWE is not helpfull at all. (i) it can't be compiled since you use packages which we haven't (ii) it call your files with content, which we haven't, (iii) you not provide part of text, where you observe your error. How one can help you? By the way, `hyperref` package is normally last in the preamble.

Comment: After removing the bits that I don't have (specifically your document class and srcltx.sty) and using a book class instead, the code provided generates no errors. As MickG suggested, you need to make a copy of your failing document, and start commenting out parts until you can isolate a few lines causing the error. Additionally, the preamble is very outdated or redundant in several locations: graphicx supersedes graphics and epsfig, for example. subfigure is twice-deprecated, first by subfig, and later by subcaption.

Comment: Since the `pfe` and `./styles/srcltx` are not present in my system, I changed the first to `book` and removed the second one. I made a folder `chapters` and a subfolder `chap1`. As shown in the screen shot below, the result compiles in my system and the figure appears (I've used a dummy figure). Other than what seems to be encoding problems, there are no errors in your MWE. http://imgur.com/GRtTOy7

Comment: i have uploaded the thesis folders. the problem appear when i add a caption to the table or the figure.

Comment: I have the impression the class is the problem. And seeing `% caption %%% ATTENTION CE N'est PAS forcement supporté par toutes les
% distrib LateX` in the class file confirms my suspicion :).

Comment: Is your LaTeX distributoin up to date?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290859/error-while-including-subcaption-package for me.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the class because when I use another template it's working correctly!! but I don't know exactly the origin of the problem in class used

Comment: I just downloaded your thesis file, and found out, that the problem was definitively https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290859/error-while-including-subcaption-package. Please update your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the `pfe` and `./styles/srcltx` are not present in my system, I changed the first to book and removed the second one. I made a folder chapters and a subfolder chap1. As shown in the screen shot below, the result compiles in my system and the figure appears (I've used a dummy figure). Other than what seems to be encoding problems, there are no errors in your MWE. [imgur.com/GRtTOy7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vMhw.jpg)

[AjN's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300646/problem-with-figure-and-table-caption#comment728184_300646).

Indeed, the offending bit is in the class file

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% caption %%% ATTENTION CE N'est PAS forcement supporté par toutes les
% distrib LateX
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\RequirePackage{caption2}

\captionstyle{centerlast}
\renewcommand\captionfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\captionlabelfont{\bfseries\itshape}
%\setcaptionmargin{\leftmargini}
%\setlength\captionindent{\parindent}
\renewcommand\captionlabeldelim{~---}
\onelinecaptionstrue
\setcaptionwidth{12.9999cm}
```

The comment reads:

> caption  ATTENTION THIS is NOT necessarily supported by all LateX distribs.

I tried having a look at the package documentation for `caption2`, which seemed to be the source of the problem, and in the compatibility section I found:

> Das Paket caption und seine experimentelle, nun veraltete Variante caption2 sind vom internen Konzept her zu unterschiedlich, um hier eine vollständige Kompatibilität gewährleisten zu können. Daher liegt diesem Paket weiterhin die Datei caption2.sty bei, so daß ältere Dokumente, die das caption2-Paket verwenden, weiterhin übersetzt werden können.

which Google translates to:

> The package caption and its experimental and now obsolete variant caption2 have Conceptually too different to here to be able to ensure full compatibility. Therefore, this package is still in the caption2.sty file so that old documents using the caption2 package will still compile.

So the question is: why does your class use an obsolete version of a package? Please update that class so that it doesn't, and I bet the problem will go away.

**Update**

I modified the offending bit in the class following the instructions in the documentation, and now it looks like this:

```
\RequirePackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont={bf,it}]{caption}

\captionsetup{justification=centerlast,singlelinecheck=on}
%\renewcommand\captionfont{\footnotesize}
%\renewcommand\captionlabelfont{\bfseries\itshape}
%\setcaptionmargin{\leftmargini}
%\setlength\captionindent{\parindent}
\newcommand\captionlabeldelim{~---}
%\onelinecaptionstrue
\setcaptionwidth{12.9999cm}
```

and everything compiles, and the format seems more or less the same as the original.

Btw, the error I got was completely different:

```
Runaway argument?
{\parbox [b]\captionlinewidth {\strut \@nameuse {caption@@@centerlast\ETC.
./chapters/chap1.tex:15: Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.15 ...ns possibles du hamza en association avec}
```

There still seem to be encoding problems in your document. `TeXShop` warned me that it had to open one of your documents in `IsoLatin8` encoding. Please make sure everything is in the same encoding, best if `UTF-8`. At the moment, the output pdf looks like this:

[image]

**Update 2**

Exactly why would your class load `inputenc` with encoding `latin1`, when `utf8` is decidedly always better, and `latin1` causes the encoding problems? And did you know that it did? Seeing as you called it from your document, I guess you didn't. Please take your class and change the encoding option for `inputenc` from `latin1` to `utf8`, and the encoding problems (or most of them) will vanish. With this result:

[image]

And since I'm editing, here is my now-deleted comment:

> Also, LaTeX doesn't particularly like having to fetch packages from specified folders, since it seems the folder name is part of the package name and when it finds the file it says "NO, this does not provide `./styles/pfe` but just `pfe`" ;). The ?? for the figure reference obviously clears up on second compilation.

And it cleared up in the encoding-fixed version.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response I tried to do the required step, but I still have the following problem:! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�cr not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: That is an entirely different question. What line is the error reported on?

Comment: Try pinpointing the exact line of the error. The error message should give you a number, and if you look at the lines before the message it should tell you what file you are in. Or else it should show a portion of that line. Find it, and paste it here. I'll see what the offending Unicode char is.

Comment: i have modified the class file the encoding to utf8 by modifying the class file \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}  i get this error

Comment: When you put code in a comment, question or answer, please surround it with backticks. `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is much better than \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}, don't you think? It greatly improves readability. Backticks are ` ` `.

Comment: And as I said, if you look at th error message, it should start with `l. <>`, where <> is a number. And it should give you a portion of that line. Find that line in your files, and post it as a comment here. I will analyze it character by character to see if I find the offending character. If you have a Mac, you can just paste the line in the Character Viewer and see if there are any strange characters in it.

Comment: Or you can try switching to `XeTeX` (well, right, `XeLaTeX`) and finding a suitable font to circumvent this problem and just remove `inputenc` from your document.

Comment: I got that error many times with the "non-breakable space", which I accidentally typed due to a keyboard shortcut on my mac, something like Shift+Space->non-breakable space. If it's the same with you, you can try adding `\catcode\`\ =\active\def {\space}` to your preamble and see if it stops the error.

Comment: And no, the spaces in the code I just gave are not plain spaces. They are NO-BREAK SPACEs.

Comment: I think because I'm writing in French I get this error the line number 1 causing errors contains"écritiure"

Comment: You mean "écriture" :). Anyway perhaps the `.tex` file for chapter 1 is saved in a wrong encoding.

Comment: yes I mean  "écriture" . how can i change the encoding please. when i open my file texmaker suggest me to open it on ISO-8859-1 because it will not be correctly opened in UTF8.

Comment: Make a new document, save it as UTF8, then copy-paste everything into it. That should create a document with the same contents, but UTF8. Use that instead of the old one. How to save as UTF8? No idea :). I figured it out long ago in TeXShop and I forgot how. I have never used TeXMaker, so you'll have to figure things out on your own.

Comment: Or you can try seeing if `\catcode\`\é=\active\defé{\'e}` added to the preamble fixes the problem.

Comment: Did that thing work? Or did you manage to change the encoding of the file?

Comment: I have changed the pfe. sty with a new one downloaded from the net and its works well. I tried to get the easiest solution. this class has many problems

Comment: Always update your files before posting questions :). Now to mark this question as answered, please consider clicking the checkmark next to my answer to "accept" it.

Comment: The `caption` package documentation is available in English, too, so there is no need to post a paragraph translated by the Google translator. (But since I'm German the Google translation might even more comprehensive than my English version ;-))

Comment: @Sommerfeldt I either don't have it in English or `texdoc` didn't find it. I used the TeXShop "show info for package" dialog (or whatever it's called), typed `caption2`, hit OK and the German version was opened. Which is why I ever read it in German :)

Comment: @MickG With "texdoc caption" I get the English version, with "texdoc caption2" I get the German version of the `caption` package documentation. (TeXlive 2015 on Linux) This is really strange. However, there is an English, a German, and a Russian version of the documentation available: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption